# Corrupt zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Setup: 3 node cluster. Each node has a zookeeper and Kafka.

While trying out Kafka, we created 10000 topics within 5 minutes. Afterwards, zookeeper got corrupted. Though brokers are up "**ls /brokers/ids**", it shows "[]". I can see that brokers are up and running. Some producers were pushing messages to brokers without any issue. Some producers are getting error.

I know that creating too many short topics is not recommended. However, I would like to understand how creating too many topics corrupted zookeeper. Also some producers were working fine and some were not.

After restarting Kafka brokers one by one, zookeeper started show them in "ls /brokers/ids".

Can someone please help me understand this chaotic behavior of zookeeper?

Comment: Why do you think Zookeeper was corrupted? It could be the brokers losing their connection to Zookeeper. Could you attach relevant logs from the brokers?

Comment: I have updated original question to make it more clear. After creating 1000s of topics in small time, when I run "ls /brokers/ids"; I get [].